# Replicate multiple on-site SQL Server databases to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication

I have a SQL Server Express 2014 named instance containing 3 databases
(One for each office). connected to a WinForms application.

Each database is uniquely named after the respective office although containing the exact same tables & table names with different data.

I want to set up transactional replication from the local databases to Azure.
Will having the same table names in different databases create a problem when replicating to Azure?

What would be the best workaround for this? The 3 databases cannot be merged into one and renaming the table names create problems when using the Winforms application.